# Server Error with rvest in R

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping, rcurl, rvest

I'm no expert in webscraping, but have enjoyed using rvest in R.   Today I tried to use it to scrape a particular fitness site called JeFit and I got the following error.  Here is my input and output:

```
library(rvest)
html("https://www.jefit.com/")

 Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
```

I'm having trouble understanding why rvest works for other sites I try but not this one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that's no an R problem. there's a problem that site's cert.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to get around it from my side?

Comment: don't know R at all, but maybe there's a way to loose or disable ssl cert checking stuff.

Comment: Worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look up your user agent and put that in html function.

ua <- "just google what is my user agent to find this"

html("https://www.jefit.com/",httr::user_agent(ua))